Interactive Azure AD Authentication error
Inputs :

Web api app hosted in Azure
App in Azure AD registered as a public client (for graph api
purposes, I need an Interactive auth mode)

Locally, everything works well. I have set the redirectUri in the Azure app to http://localhost - the default for Mobile and desktop applications registration. However, when attempting to authorize in Interactive mode, I get the following error:
MSAL.NetCore.4.61.3.0.MsalClientException:
    ErrorCode: http_listener_error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:49738/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.
 ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()

The port 49738 is always different. I haven't run the netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1 command yet. Should I? And where can I find this Admin command prompt? Maybe it’s better to run the web app in Azure on a specific port and set it in the redirect URL in Azure AD? But when I register a public client I can use only WithDefaultRedirectUrl() // http:localhost
Code for getting auth token :
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
      .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}

I think the problem is not in the code or in Azure Ad. I think that the web app has a problem with access to Azure Ad, apparently some setting is missing

Can you update your question by sharing the code ?

@PratikJadhav issue updated. Nothing special in the code, just a default realization

Have you added web app url  in redirect uri  ServicePrincipal?
